# Can an Azure Devops build get only the source files covered by my path filters?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When setting up a build config, I can go to the *Triggers* page and provide a list of specific folder paths. This makes it so a new build is only triggered if a file changes under those paths.

However, if all the source code in my repo is available to the build, it can accidentally depend on files that won't trigger a new build when they change. Thus a build (and later deployment) will not happen when it ought to. Some of my deployments will continue to run stale code that was built into their artefacts.

To defend against this and make the filtering feature safe, I need to make the source-getting step automatically prune the sources according to the filter paths, leaving only those files that are being tracked so they trigger builds.

Or at least I need a subsequent task in the build config that performs that same pruning automatically according to the filter path config.

Are either of these possible today in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Are you talking about a Git repo or a TFVC repo?

Comment: In my case, Git.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you're going to have to manually synchronize your source code and get clever with the Git CLI. What you're looking for is called a *sparse checkout*.

It's also worth considering whether it makes sense to keep everything in the same repo if you're having this kind of problem. You can break things into multiple repos and use submodules, or (for shared dependencies), convert them into packages, build them independently, and publish them to a package feed.

Comment: Yes, multirepo/submodules is our current solution, the idea here is to explore the simplest possible form of monorepo, as that would remove a lot of tiresome and unnecessary activity. Also a key point is to configure the paths once and have that determine both what is checked out and what is watched. When would it make sense to rebuild when some things change but not others? Seems like that would be very much the minority case.